# How do I set a featured image for the homepage?

Tags: facebook

How do I set a featured image for the homepage? I am not concerned with the outcome of having or not having a featured image within wordpress itself. I want to control the featured image when it gets used via an external link, for example facebook.

Comment: What do you mean by "control"?

Comment: This appears to be a Facebook API question, rather than a WordPress question...

Comment: @Joseph control means set and change the image.

Comment: @ChipBennett it's for FB mainly, but I would like to also control it for other services.

Answer (score 3):

If it's **only** for Facebook purposes that you need it, you could add the following code to your header.php file (between `<head>` and `</head>`):

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>`

Of course replace the URL in `content="..."` with your own image URL.

A reference for all the Facebook meta tags is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Comment: Thanks. It's mainly for FB, but I would like to also control it for other services.